# can't import AVI type 1 to premiere CS6

Tags: premiere, editing

Bs''d

Hi!
I used to work with premiere pro CS4.1 now I'm working with CS6, I moved to project folder to        my new computer, but when open it I get an error "damaged or un-supported file"
The AVI file works fine in CS4(at the old computer) and in media player in my new computer.

Thanks you all for your answering :)

My old system works poorly so it not good idea to export in it. I'm not sure I want to use AME because I need a very good output and if I will do so I will lose generation and/or quality

here is some details:

the file codec is dvsd (DVC/DV Video)

Complete name                            : D:\Natural Health B 2 B.avi
Format                                   : AVI
Format/Info                              : Audio Video Interleave
Commercial name                          : DV
Format profile                           : OpenDML
File size                                : 12.4 GiB
Duration                                 : 1h 1mn
Overall bit rate mode                    : Constant
Overall bit rate                         : 28.9 Mbps
Recorded date                            : 2011-06-21 17:57:45.000

ID                                       : 0
Format                                   : DV
Duration                                 : 1h 1mn
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 24.4 Mbps
Encoded bit rate                         : 28.8 Mbps
Width                                    : 720 pixels
Height                                   : 576 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 25.000 fps
Standard                                 : PAL
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Interlaced
Scan order                               : Bottom Field First
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 2.357
Time code of first frame                 : 00:59:16:07
Time code source                         : Subcode time code
Stream size                              : 12.4 GiB (100%)
Encoding settings                        : ae mode=manual / wb mode=automatic / white balance= / fcm=manual focus

Comment: A MediaInfo (http://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) output of the file would be very helpful.

Comment: As Professor Sparkle pointed out, we really need more information about the file.  Most likely it sounds like a codec issue.  There are multiple types of codecs that can be used by different programs, most likely the type that supports the file is not the same type that is used by Premiere.

Comment: Thank you for answering as you can see above I've added some details

Answer (score 1):

> the file codec is dvsd (DVC/DV Video)

Usually DirectX comes with a DirectShow DVSD decoder. But maybe this decoder has some issue with your file(s).
Could it be you've had at some time software by Pinnacle, Sony, MainConcept, etc on your old system installed, whose DVSD decoder could have been used by Premiere Pro instead?

Answer (score 0):

> Without knowinf more about the specific codec used on the file we can't say much.

One thing you can try is transcoding it with Adobe Media Encoder to another format that you know will work in CS6

Comment: It is worth noting that you would likely have to export on the old system though.  If Premiere can't handle the file, there is a relatively good chance Media Encoder will also fail to handle it.

Comment: That is likely, although I've run into  this similar issue and AME transcoded it and it worked fine in PP afterward.

Comment: yeah, that's why I said relatively good chance and didn't down vote. ;)  I was more just commenting for the OP's sake to let them know if it doesn't work, it probably isn't that they are doing something wrong, just that there are a limited number of cases where AME transcoding will make a difference.